# ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified from Window Service

Tags: odbc, sybase, sap-iq

i have created a windows service which needs to connect to Sybase database using ODBC connection in regular intervals and process data. I am getting below error when i am trying to open ODBC connection in windows service class (say "StarterClass") method (Say "StartMethod").

**ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified**

I am sure that the connection string is fine. I gave my windows service reference to another test web application. And try to call same windows service class method.

The connection is opening successfully in debug mode. but when i deploy the service, its giving problem.

Kindly help me,

Regards

Venkat

Answer (score 0):

You probably defined a USER datasource instead of a SYSTEM datasource. When the service runs, it runs as a different user usually.